# How to specify dtype correctly in python when dealing with complex numbers and numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I need to check whether a matrix is unitary in python, for that I use this function:

```
def is_unitary(m):
    return np.allclose(np.eye(m.shape[0]), m.H * m)
```

but when I'm trying to specify a matrix by:

```
m1=np.matrix([complex(1/math.sqrt(2)),cmath.exp(1j)],[-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(),complex(1/math.sqrt(2))],dtype=complex)
```

I get a

```
TypeError: __new__() got multiple values for argument 'dtype'
```

What is the correct way of working with data types here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use `np.matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use), it's almost always the wrong choice, especially if you use Python 3.5+. You should rather use `np.array`.

Besides, you forgot to put `[` and `]` around the values, so what you "thought" you passed in as "second row" was actually a second argument. And the second argument for `array` (and `matrix`) is interpreted by NumPy as the `dtype`:

```
np.array([[complex(1/math.sqrt(2)),     cmath.exp(1j)          ],
          [-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(), complex(1/math.sqrt(2))]],
         dtype=complex)
# array([[ 0.70710678+0.j        ,  0.54030231+0.84147098j],
#        [-0.54030231-0.84147098j,  0.70710678+0.j        ]])
```

Comment: Oh! The brackets! Thank you, it worked. I will switch to using arrays!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it works. Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `matrix` constructor only takes the **first** argument as data, and the second as `dtype`, so it sees your *second row* `[-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(),complex(1/math.sqrt(2))]` as `dtype`.

You need to pass a nested list, so add square brackets:

```
m1=np.matrix([[complex(1/math.sqrt(2)),cmath.exp(1j)],[-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(),complex(1/math.sqrt(2))]],dtype=complex)
#            ^                                                                                             ^
```

Or perhaps more elegant:

```
m1=np.matrix([
              [complex(1/math.sqrt(2)),cmath.exp(1j)],
              [-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(),complex(1/math.sqrt(2))]
             ],dtype=complex)
```

This then produces:

```
>>> m1
matrix([[ 0.70710678+0.j        ,  0.54030231+0.84147098j],
        [-0.54030231-0.84147098j,  0.70710678+0.j        ]])
```

The same holds for `array` by the way:

```
m1=np.array([
              [complex(1/math.sqrt(2)),cmath.exp(1j)],
              [-cmath.exp(-1j).conjugate(),complex(1/math.sqrt(2))]
            ],dtype=complex)
```

producing:

```
>>> m1
array([[ 0.70710678+0.j        ,  0.54030231+0.84147098j],
       [-0.54030231-0.84147098j,  0.70710678+0.j        ]])
```